# Is this knotted graph knotted?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, knot-theory, knot-invariants

[image: Knotted graph]

Above, I've drawn a knotted 3-valent graph. I suspect that it's not isotopic to the "unknotted" version below, but I'm not sure. Is it?

I know about fundamental groups of knot complements, but it seems like that's probably more work than necessary. The easiest way would be to show that it's the companion of some simple knot, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

Is this knotted (by which I mean, is that not-equals sign in the drawing correct), and if so, is there a good way to prove that?

Comment: It seems to be related to the so-called "Hopf handcuffs".

Comment: Specifically, you can obtain it by doing [this transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm7b1.jpg) to the Hopf handcuffs. Maybe there's a lemma that says that that transformation preserves knottedness?

Comment: (We can iterate that transformation as many times as we like - probably _all_ those iterations are knotted. A fundamental group computation seems kinda inevitable now…)

Comment: I vaguely remember Rolfsen's book having a section on an iterated "chain" transformation (used to describe Antoine's necklace). Unfortunately I don't have that book with me so I can't reference it to see how he did it, but maybe we need a similar strategy.

Comment: Ah. At the end of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412486), the Jones polynomial is used to show that this is, in fact, knotted.

Comment: [Here's a much better reference](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdfplus/10.1142/S0218216511009893?casa_token=2Ipc104m6NgAAAAA:qDCUM1FWf8jUNtSh63q7Cj8Yg6rV0OsU-AqWmiietJM-FM09c1f3eQ6B_k7LVoyoNpsmK4ssdA). They consider "knotted handlebodies", which are these knotted graphs (or "spatial graphs") up to IH moves (moves that replace an H shape with a sideways H shape). They make a table of the smallest knotted handlebodies. The first graph in my image is 6_10; the second is 0_1 (up to an IH move).

Comment: (Paywall or university account only, apparently)

Comment: (or, y'know, sci-hub)